# Why does the subquery with count(*) return multiple values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a student table and address table. I want to find out what percentage of them come from London.
I have a query that looks like

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student
INNER JOIN address on student.address_id = address.id 
WHERE city = 'Lodon')/ COUNT(*)  FROM student
```

When I run this query I get an error

> SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student               ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? When I run the subquery separately it returns a single value, but why does it return multiple values when I put in a subquery? Also, if there is a cleaner query please suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG( CASE WHEN a.city = 'London' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM student s JOIN
     address a
     ON a.address_id = s.id ;
```

Your query returns an error because subqueries with aggregation queries are tricky.